# Linux detect native memory leak within a Java application

Tags: java, linux, memory, native

Is there a tool or way to detect which part of a Java web application/web server leaks native memory in RedHat Linux? Is there any free profiling tool that can be used to find out what cause memory consumption to increase within the application/server?

Comment: Can you define memory leak? Java has a garbage collector, so you don't have the same types of leaks that you would with C++, or similar language. Ultimately, you can create a memory leak, but essentially, you'd have to try.

Comment: In java a memory leak can happen from a reference that is held to an object that is no longer being used.  The garbage collector will not clean it up.